# Why does the number below validates as an integer in json schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Given the schema:

```json
{
  "properties": {
    "value": { "type": "integer" }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

the value:

```
{
  "value": 1.1111111111111112E+28
}
```

validates successfully. Why is 1.1111111111111112E+28 is treated as an integer?

Comment: It is one, as far as we can tell from the number of significant figures available: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1.1111111111111112E%2B28

Comment: Blimey it is one!